# Error when trying to do TeX input with ImportString[]

Tags: notebooks, latex, input

I got this information from here (Last line of the details section): https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/menuitem/InlineTeXInput.html

My code:

```
ImportString["2^2", "TeX"]
```

Output:

```
$Failed
```

Why my output is not:

```
4
```

Comment: Yes, this does not work. Also using "LaTeX" does not work either. I wonder if this every worked.

Comment: TeX is for typesetting rather than calculations so I wouldn't expect `4` but `Superscript[2, 2]`. Having that in mind, does this fit your needs? `ImportString["\\[" <> "2^2" <> "\\]", "TeX"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code does not work because `2^2` is not a valid TeX input (it will also not work if you use it in any other TeX compiler). That is because character `^` can be used only in mathematical environment.

```
ImportString["2^2", "TeX"]
(* $Failed *)

ImportString["$2^2$", "TeX"]
(* Notebook[{Cell[
    TextData[{Cell[
      BoxData[FormBox[SuperscriptBox["2", "2"], TraditionalForm]], 
      "InlineFormula"], "  "}], "Text"]}, 
    StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"] *)

ImportString["$$2^2$$", "TeX"]
(* Notebook[{Cell[TextData[{}], "Text"], 
    Cell[BoxData[FormBox[SuperscriptBox["2", "2"], TraditionalForm]], 
     "NumberedEquation"]}, StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"] *)

ImportString["\\[2^2\\]", "TeX"]
(* Notebook[{Cell[TextData[{}], "Text"], 
    Cell[BoxData[FormBox[SuperscriptBox["2", "2"], TraditionalForm]], 
     "NumberedEquation"]}, StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"] *)
```

If you only want to directly convert (and evaluate) the expression, use [`ToExpression`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToExpression.html).

```
ToExpression["2^2", TeXForm]
(* 4 *)
```